# Cookieに要素をクリックしたらKEYを保存する

Tags: php, jquery, css

Cookieを用いて要素の表示・非表示を行いたいのですが、うまくいきません。

求めている一連の動作は、

１：要素A,B,C ← 要素別にクリックしたらKEYを保存
２：ページにアクセス時、クリック時に保存したKEYの有無の確認・取得
３：クリックしていないのであれば、display:none;している要素をdisplay:block;させる

といった処理を行いたいのですが、Cookieには疎く求めている動作を実現させることができません。

文章での説明なので、わかり辛いとは思いますが、どなたかお力を貸していただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie を利用するのも手ですが……。
cookieって、サーバー側へ自動送信して、サーバー側で何か処理するためのというイメージがあります。

質問にあるような目的であればSessionStorageを使うべきだと思います。
SessionStorageを使った場合は、サーバー側で何かする必要もなく
JavaScriptだけの世界に閉じるので私ならそうします。
（参考：http://www.htmq.com/webstorage/）

jquery-cookieもSessionStorageもKVSライクに書けるので
どちらかを使うべきだと思います。

Comment: jquery-cookieを使用して、解決することができました。
ありがとうございました。